# Change an <h1> based on URL with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am setting up a test in Optimizely that will run on a number of pages. The pages are identical with the exception of the headline, but unfortunately if you change any HTML it ends up hard coding the headline into the variation design.

I'm just really learning JS and so far I've butchered the script.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if(window.location.href.indexOf("calculate-metal-roofing-costs") > -1)
    $("h1").text("Request Your Metal Roofing Cost Estimates");
}  else {
if(window.location.href.indexOf("calculate-shingle-squares") > -1)
    $("h1").text("Request Your Shingle Estimates");
});
```

Can anyone help me with this, even just aim this unfortunate soul in the right direction? Any responses will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can u provides us a fiddle with example?

Comment: Looks like you're missing some brackets there to open up the "if" statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("calculate-metal-roofing-costs") > -1) {
    $("h1").text("Request Your Metal Roofing Cost Estimates");
  }
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("calculate-shingle-squares") > -1) {
    $("h1").text("Request Your Shingle Estimates");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Lee! This looks like it is working and I learned something!

Comment: So I changed
window.location.href.indexOf("metal")
to
(/metal/.test(self.location.href))
which helped identify the page better, but everything else remained the same.